# Simulate network offline - Servlet java

Tags: java, servlets, server, offline

I have a Servlet and i want to response(?) or simulate a server offline. 
To send a HTTP response status code does not make sense and it is not the same. 
How can i handle this?

Comment: You must explain better what "offline" means to you here.

Comment: Sorry. If the client make a request, the server should not be available

Comment: Don't start the container?  (Tomcat/Jetty/etc)

Comment: that would be too easy ;) .. i have 2 Servlet. The other Servlet have to available the whole time.

Comment: Nobody has any idea what it is you want to do.